# Adding UITextFields one below another on button click in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I have a UIScrollView with multiple components.I need to add UITextfields in such a way that on tap of a button the textfields will get add one below another vertically.for eg if button tapped 100 times.100 uitextfields should get added, also there are components below this uitextfield so the uiscrollview should adjust its height accordingly.

Comment: what you have tried ? also is this **one below another horizontally** clear ?????

Comment: Use a `UIStackView` and add each text field as an arranged subview. The stack view will automatically expand, and its constraints will automatically handle the scroll view content size.

Comment: sh_khan .sorry but its vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Note:*** Original answer edited with fill / get example code.

Here is a simple example.

Add a `UIStackView` (vertical axis) to the scroll view. With each button tap, create a new `UITextField` and add it as an `arrangedSubview` of the stack view.

The stack view will automatically expand vertically, and its constraints will automatically handle the scroll view's content size.

- The new fields will be initialized with Placeholder strings.
- Tapping the "Fill Fields" button will then set the text of each field to a value from a sample data array.
- Tapping the "Get Text" button will log the text of each field to the debug console.

**ViewController.h**

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 12/3/19.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 12/3/19.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *theButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *fillButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *getButton;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIScrollView *theScrollView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIStackView *theStackView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *theData;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    // instantiate buttons, scrollView and stackViews

    // adds a new text field
    _theButton = [UIButton new];
    [_theButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [_theButton setTitle:@"Add Field" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_theButton setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [_theButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    // fills the fields with sample data
    _fillButton = [UIButton new];
    [_fillButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [_fillButton setTitle:@"Fill Fields" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_fillButton setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [_fillButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    // logs the text of each field to debug console
    _getButton = [UIButton new];
    [_getButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [_getButton setTitle:@"Get Text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_getButton setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [_getButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    // scroll view will hold the stack view filled with fields
    _theScrollView = [UIScrollView new];
    [_theScrollView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [_theScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];

    // stack view to hold the new fields
    _theStackView = [UIStackView new];
    [_theStackView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [_theStackView setAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
    [_theStackView setSpacing:8.0];

    // stack view for buttons
    UIStackView *buttonsStackView = [UIStackView new];
    [buttonsStackView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [buttonsStackView setAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
    [buttonsStackView setSpacing:8.0];

    // add buttons to the buttons stack view
    [buttonsStackView addArrangedSubview:_theButton];
    [buttonsStackView addArrangedSubview:_fillButton];
    [buttonsStackView addArrangedSubview:_getButton];

    // add button stack view and scrollView to view
    [self.view addSubview:buttonsStackView];
    [self.view addSubview:_theScrollView];

    // add stackView to scrollView
    [_theScrollView addSubview:_theStackView];

    UILayoutGuide *g = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide;
    UILayoutGuide *sg = _theScrollView.contentLayoutGuide;

    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[

        // constrain buttons 20-pts from top, centered horizontally
        [buttonsStackView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor constant:20.0],
        [buttonsStackView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.centerXAnchor constant:0.0],

        // constrai scrollView 20-pts below button, 20-pts on each side and bottom
        [_theScrollView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_theButton.bottomAnchor constant:20.0],
        [_theScrollView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.bottomAnchor constant:-20.0],
        [_theScrollView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor constant:20.0],
        [_theScrollView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor constant:-20.0],

        // constrain stackView 8-pts on each side
        [_theStackView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:sg.topAnchor constant:8.0],
        [_theStackView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:sg.bottomAnchor constant:-8.0],
        [_theStackView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:sg.leadingAnchor constant:8.0],
        [_theStackView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:sg.trailingAnchor constant:-8.0],

        // constrain stackView width to scrollView frame width minus 16-pts (for 8-pts on each side)
        [_theStackView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_theScrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor constant:-16.0],

        ]
    ];

    [_theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_fillButton addTarget:self action:@selector(fillFields:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_getButton addTarget:self action:@selector(getFields:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // sample data to fill the fields with
    NSString *s = @"This is just random text that will be used to fill the text fields when the fill button is tapped";
    _theData = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@" "].mutableCopy;

}

- (void)fillFields:(id)sender {
    // set the text of each field based on the data array
    NSInteger idx = 0;
    for (UITextField *f in _theStackView.arrangedSubviews) {
        // make sure we don't have more fields than our data array
        if (idx < _theData.count) {
            f.text = _theData[idx++];
        }
    }
}

- (void)getFields:(id)sender {
    // log the text of each field to debug cosole
    for (UITextField *f in _theStackView.arrangedSubviews) {
        NSLog(@"%@", f.text);
    }
}

- (void)addTextField:(id)sender {

    // instantiate a new text field
    UITextField *f = [UITextField new];
    [f setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [f setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    // add it to the stack view
    [_theStackView addArrangedSubview:f];

    // set its placeholder text (just to make it easy to see what we're doing)
    [f setPlaceholder:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Text Field %ld", _theStackView.arrangedSubviews.count]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // auto-scroll to bottom so newly added text field is visible
        CGRect r = CGRectMake(0.0, self.theScrollView.contentSize.height - 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        [self.theScrollView scrollRectToVisible:r animated:YES];

    });

}

@end
```

Result after 3 taps:

[image]

after enough taps to need to scroll:

[image]

and after tapping the "Fill Fields" button:

[image]

Comment: DonMag -Thank u so much for thi,need one more help from you.how to get reference of each of textfields? I want to add data in each textfield and send them through api call.

Comment: Well, you could add them to an array as you create them... or, if those are the only elements in your stack view reference them as an array by `_theStackView.arrangedSubviews`.

Comment: I need data filled in each and every textfield..I tried using array but textfield.text is always nil as it is creating new textfield on every click.so not able to maintain the array.

Comment: @DonMag-Thank you so much.You have been a saviour.

Comment: @roshan.k - if this answered your question, be sure to mark it as "accepted" (for the benefit of other users who may come across it).